# How can I execute an application on android with qemu?

Tags: android, qemu

How can I execute an app without booting and loading all the android system on qemu (user-mode emulation)? PS: a Java app, not a C one.

Comment: Hello - I know this is 8 years old. Did you figure out how to run a Java program on QEMU user-mode? I am on x86 and want to emulate ARM Java program. I don't think I can get Java for ARM installed on x86. What I mean is, if I run .../.../qemu-arm java <my-java-program> ... 'java' is an x86 binary, so qemu-arm cannot run it... (I am on Debian so if I dpkg the java-for-arm.deb archive, Debian yells at me for wrong architecture, obviously).